# Zoo package compilation error

Tags: r, zoo

I'm running RStudio Server and am unable to install the `zoo` package. The error message I get is as follows:

> Installing package(s) into ‘/home/tsajid/R/library’
>       (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>       trying URL 'http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/src/contrib/zoo_1.7-9.tar.gz'
>       Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 807084 bytes (788 Kb)
>       opened URL
>       ==================================================
>       downloaded 788 Kb
>
> ** installing *source* package ‘zoo’ ...
>       ** package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>       ** libs
>       sh: make: command not found
>       ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘zoo’
>       ** removing ‘/home/tsajid/R/library/zoo’
>       Warning in install.packages :
>         installation of package ‘zoo’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>           ‘/tmp/RtmpsKlJWz/downloaded_packages’

I tried installing the package archive file but I get an identical error message.

Session info:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] svMisc_0.9-65

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: Have you installed all the tools necessary for building packages on your server?

Comment: Did you install all the necessary tools required to build packages from source?

Comment: I wasn't involved in setting up the RStudio environment so I wasn't aware, but this was the underlying cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It states it pretty clearly:

```
sh: make: command not found
```

So please do install the Red Hat equivalent of the Debian / Ubuntu command

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

which via its dependence on `build-essential` also installs `make`, `gcc` etc pp

Comment: Will that work for redhat?  I would assume it would need to use yum and I don't know what the r dev package is called because I'm too lazy to look it up.

Comment: Great, even before I could confirm that it is called R-devel on RH/FC :)